# How can I move an equation without affecting the label?

Tags: spacing, equations

I am having an issue with the automatic LaTeX equation and label formatting on one of my longer equations (see results below).

**Minimum Working Example**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in, bottom=1in,
      left=1in, right=1in}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2][red]{
\text{\oalign{$#2$\cr\color{#1}\leaders\hrule height 0.80pt\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}

\noindent Expanding the covariant derivatives then yields
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R^{\sigma}_{\mu\rho\nu} = \bar{R}^{\sigma}_{\mu\rho\nu} &+\tfrac{1}{2} \bar{g}^{\sigma\beta}\partial_{\rho}\bigl(\partial_{\mu}h_{\nu\beta} -\! \bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\mu\nu}h_{\tau\beta} -\! \Cline[Orange]{\bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\mu\beta}h_{\tau\nu}}\bigr) +\tfrac{1}{2} \bar{g}^{\sigma\beta}\partial_{\rho}\bigl(\partial_{\nu}h_{\mu\beta} -\! \bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\mu\nu}h_{\tau\beta} -\! \Cline[Magenta]{\bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\nu\beta}h_{\tau\mu}}\bigr) \\ &-\tfrac{1}{2} \bar{g}^{\sigma\beta}\partial_{\rho}\bigl(\partial_{\beta}h_{\mu\nu} -\! \Cline[Orange]{\bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\beta\mu}h_{\tau\nu}} -\! \Cline[Magenta]{\bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\beta\nu}h_{\tau\mu}}\bigr) -\tfrac{1}{2} \bar{g}^{\sigma\alpha}\partial_{\nu}\bigl(\partial_{\mu}h_{\rho\alpha} -\! \bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\mu\rho}h_{\tau\alpha} -\! \Cline[Green]{\bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\mu\alpha}h_{\tau\rho}}\bigr) \\ &-\tfrac{1}{2} \bar{g}^{\sigma\alpha}\partial_{\nu}\bigl(\partial_{\rho}h_{\mu\alpha} -\! \bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\rho\mu}h_{\tau\alpha} -\! \Cline[Blue]{\bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\rho\alpha}h_{\tau\mu}}\bigr) +\tfrac{1}{2} \bar{g}^{\sigma\alpha}\partial_{\nu}\bigl(\partial_{\alpha}h_{\mu\rho} -\! \Cline[Green]{\bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\alpha\mu}h_{\tau\rho}} -\! \Cline[Blue]{\bar{\Gamma}^{\tau}_{\alpha\rho}h_{\tau\mu}}\bigr).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
With the symmetries of the Christoffel symbols, the underlined terms cancel, whereas the
\end{document}
```

**Equation (0.10)**

The MWE above gives the result
[image]

I think this looks ugly.

**Equation (0.9)**

Here is what the same equation looks like if you delete on of the $a=b$ equation:

[image]

I think that this formatting looks better, with the label at the side. LaTeX is obviously following some predefined rule about spacing, the label won't fit in the above example, so it puts it at the bottom. Is there a nice way to over-rule this? Or, is there a way to move my equation slightly to the left so that the label would fit according to what LaTeX 'thinks' is best.

Comment: The problem is that your label gets too wide...

Comment: Perhaps split before the first `+`? That also separates the part of the formula you are really messing with...

Comment: @vonbrand's first comment: You don't say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quick hack and not exactly user-friendly, but a simple `\hspace{-1cm}` right after `\begin{split}` does the trick:

[image: output]

Of course you can mess with the actual value inside `\hspace` to your fancy, so long as it's negative (a positive argument will obviously move it to the right).

Comment: I would prefer `\mkern-5mu`

Comment: Plain TeX is weird. While I barely know what that means, `\hspace` is more clear as to what it's doing.  What does `\mkern` do differently from `\hspace` (or `\kern`, for all that matters)?

Comment: @vermiculus -- your hack assumes that the two text lines shown begin paragraphs.  otherwise, the equation will be shifted beyond the left margin, which isn't such a good idea.  and, looking at the mwe, the text does *not* begin paragraphs.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- I tried the MWE straight from the question.  When it comes right down to it, the only other option is somehow altering the size of the reference (possibly rotation? it would be interesting to see), the spacing/sizing of the mathematics, rearrange the equation itself, or sacrifice the margins.  It is *by all means* a hack, but it's one that seems to get the job done for this application.  Other applications will undoubtedly need fiddling with the length (or better yet, runtime-calculation of the lengths required).  It's a sacrifice.